# Implicit Complex not allowing definition?

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

I am trying to compile and run some code, however I keep getting the error Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1).

The beginning bit of the code looks like

```
      IMPLICIT COMPLEX*16 (Z)
      IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Y)
      DIMENSION X(0:40000),ZV(0:4000),ZW(0:4000)
      DIMENSION ZA(-40000:4000),ZB(-40000:4000)
      common/constants/pi,zi
      COMMON/XCO/X
      COMMON/zab/za,zb
      COMMON/RFI/T0,zga,zgb,zca1,zcb1,omd,vs,vsd,rvc
      common/nonpara/zsgmb

      OPEN(3,FILE='check.dat')
      OPEN(2,FILE='resb.dat')
      OPEN(4,FILE='resa.dat')

     pi=4.D0*datan(1.D0)
     zi=(0.D0,1.D0)

C Generate grid
      t0=-5.d0
      te=10 !15.d0                    
      nt00=1500 !2000           
      nco=nt00+1
      H=(TE-T0)/FLOAT(NT00)
      NG=3*(NCO+2)
      NT0=NT00+1
      DO 1 I=0,NG
1       X(I)=FLOAT(I-1)*H

C Artificial parameters
      zga=1.d0/5.d0                      
      zgb=1.d0
      omd=1.d0
      vs=10.d0
      phi=0.d0
      zca1=1.d0*cdexp(zi*phi)     
      zcb1=1.d0/5.d0*0.d0                
      za0=0.01d0

      zb0=0.01d0
```

When I run it in the terminal, I get the following

```
dyn1239-223:testing Alex$ gfortran amp-nonparallel.f
amp-nonparallel.f:59:7:

   zb0=0.01d0
       1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
dyn1239-223:testing Alex$
```

I don't understand what the problem is with the way this is being defined as compared to everything before this. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: included full command line input/output

Comment: Do not use implicit typing. It is really, really terrible idea for any new code. Find some textbook or tutorial written in this century. Don't use this form od DO loops, use `END DO` instead. Do not use `datan`, just `atan` is fine since the 1970's. The same for  `cdexp` and `exp`.

Comment: How do you *"run "* it in the terminal? Please show the complete code ([mcve]). I don't see any connection between the `implicit complex` and the error you show. Should there be some connection?

Comment: Ok, what about the rest of the code? We cannot test it without he *complete* code.

Comment: I inherited it with all of the `datan` etc. I'm more interested in why it is saying that the statement is unclassifiable. I seriously doubt that the way the DO loops are constructed is having an impact on that. The full code is hundreds of lines long, it would be impractical. `zga`,`zgb`,`zca1`,`zcb1` and `za0` all work fine. I was hoping someone would highlight what was wrong with `zb0`

Comment: No they have just serious impact on the readability of the code. Please show the rest of the code.

Comment: Your code can be compiled  just fine if you fix the indentations of lines `pi=4.D0*datan(1.D0)
     zi=(0.D0,1.D0)`. Is that present in your real code? Pleas DO read [mcve] and post the **complete** code we can try to compile.

Comment: I didn't realize that complex vars could be declared without the syntax like `zb0 = (0.01d, 0.0d)`. Apparently the second component defaults to zero. Also, I can confirm that a simple program that declares these variables as you've shown them and prints them to the console compiles/runs with `ifort` on my system.

Comment: Sometimes you get this error if you have a function or other variable with the same name. Since you have an awful lot of `zb`-like variables, perhaps you made a typo somewhere?

Comment: Many of the source-code lines seem to have one TAB character at the first column, which might be related to the "Unclassifiable statement" error. (But it is still not clear why only "zb0" gives that error...)

Answer (score 0):

The presence pf TAB characters was preventing the codes from compiling. Resetting everything to column one and indenting line by line manually fixed it. (Thanks roygvib)

As for why that one line was the first instance of a problem, I have no idea as there were TAB characters above that.